# how to search for documents which do not have particular element or having null value in the element?

Tags: xml, marklogic, marklogic-7

I want to search documents which do not have particular element or element having no child node(even text node) and the element should have a particular parent node.

for example:

**sample xmls:**

```
<root>
    <id>123</id>
    <root2>
        <number>1234</number>
    </root2>
</root>

<root>
    <id>123</id>
    <root2>
        <issue/>
        <number>1234</number>
    </root2>
</root>

<root>
    <id>123</id>
    <root2>
        <volume/>
        <number>1234</number>
    </root2>
</root>

<root-second>
    <id>123</id>
    <root2>
        <volume/>
        <issue/>
        <number>1234</number>
    </root2>
</root-second>

<root-second>
    <id>123</id>
    <root2>
        <volume/>
        <issue/>
        <number>1234</number>
    </root2>
</root-second>
```

**New Docs:**

```
<root>
    <id>123</id>
    <root2>
        <volume>233</volume>
        <number>1234</number>
    </root2>
</root>
<root>
    <id>123</id>
    <root2>
        <volume>233</volume>
        <issue>233</issue>
        <number>1234</number>
    </root2>
</root>
<root>
     <id>123</id>
     <root2>
        <issue>233</issue>
        <number>1234</number>
      </root2>
</root>
```

Now I want all xmls having `<id>` in `<root>` is **123** and `<root2>` can have empty `<issue>, <volume>` element or element(s) not present at all.

As in the above case, it should not return xmls with `<root-second>` as root.

It should return all xmls with `<root>` as root

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each XML is in its own document, you should be able to do this with:

```
cts:search(
  fn:doc(),
  cts:element-query(
    xs:QName("root"),
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("id"), "123")
  )
)
```

I'm not entirely clear on your question, but I think you might also be wanting to require that `root2` be present under root, regardless of what it might contain. If that's the case, then:

```
cts:search(
  fn:doc(),
  cts:element-query(
    xs:QName("root"),
    cts:and-query((
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("id"), "123"),
      cts:element-query(xs:QName("root2"), cts:true-query())
    ))
  )
)
```

Comment: David, I have updated my Question.
I have added new documents (Yes each XML is in its own document).

Now the new added docs should not come into the result as all the three documents has <volume>, <issue> or both elements present with some value(text node).

Yes David <roo2> should present under <root> and it should be the parent node of <volume>,<issue>
As in my case <volume>,<issue> can be present under <root3> , <root3> is also under <root> (sibling of <root2>)

Comment: cts:true-query() I can't use this as I am using ML 7

Comment: replace cts:true-query() with cts:and-query(()).